# Typescript: type guard across properties in an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript I am able to declare a function type-guard to check if a property is null or not similarly to the following:

```js
interface IApiResponse<TRecord> {
  readonly isDefined: boolean;
  readonly record: TRecord | null;
}

const responseHasRecordDefined = 
  <TRecord>(apiResponse: IApiResponse<TRecord>): apiResponse.record is TRecord => apiResponse.isDefined;
```

However I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the same task with just a single interface definition?

Like something similar to:

```js
interface IApiResponse<TRecord> {
  readonly record: TRecord | null;
  readonly isDefined: this.record is TRecord;
}
```

EDIT:

As Ryan pointed out in the comments this initial case is easily handled by a null check. So I'm adding another example of a problem that requires a type guard of some sort rather than a simple null check.

```js
interface IResponseTypeA {
  // Anything can be in here
}

interface IResponseTypeB {
  // Anything can be in here
}

interface IApiResponse {
  readonly record: IResponseTypeA | IResponseTypeB;
  readonly isTypeA: this.record is IResponseTypeA;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are checking the boolean in the type guard instead of just checking whether the `record` field is `null` directly? Is that just what some API you don’t control returns for instance?

Comment: You're correct, in the example I gave I could just check whether the `record` field is `null`.  I've updated the question to include a more generic case where the two types are no so well defined that something like a null check would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question the right way but you can do something like

```js
type IApiResponse =  {
  readonly record: IResponseTypeA;
  readonly isTypeA: true;
} | {
  readonly record: IResponseTypeB;
  readonly isTypeA: false;
}
```

and then if you have a function this would infer the type depending on the variable

```js
function foo(bar: IApiResponse){
    if (bar.isTypeA){
     /// record is not from type IResponseTypeA
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for...

which is silly since I already have this form of declaration in my project for a weird react component's props ‍♂️